# Searchkit - error after saving searches in 5.63.2

Tags: upgrade, error, searchkit

I updated my side from 5.58.1 to 5.63.2. Now as soon I save an existing searchkit search, I got an error: `"message" => "Invalid field ''"`. Before saving, the searches runs. New searches also working. Any ideas what I can do?

Thanks
David

This is the full error message:

```
Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Invalid field ''"
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#2426
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "Invalid field ''"
    #code: 0
    #file: "/var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php"
    #line: 727
    trace: {
      /var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:727 {
        Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery->getField($expr, $strict = false)
        › if ($strict && $field === NULL) {
        ›   throw new \CRM_Core_Exception("Invalid field '$fieldName'");
        › }
      }
      /var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:672 { …}
      /var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:547 { …}
      /var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:459 { …}
      /var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:823 { …}
      /var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:127 { …}
      /var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/ext/search_kit/Civi/Search/Meta.php:34 { …}
      /var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/ext/search_kit/Civi/Search/AfformSearchMetadataInjector.php:74 { …}
      Civi\Search\AfformSearchMetadataInjector::Civi\Search\{closure}() {}
      /var/www/html/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/ChangeSet.php:59 { …}
```

in browser consol the following errer is shown:
"TypeError: CRM.angular.templates is undefined"

This is my system infromation:

- CiviCRM: 5.63.2
- CMS: Drupal 7.98
- PHP: 7.4
- Database: 10.3.38 MariaDB

addional info:
The first time I updated, I got an error message because the title on the civicrm_contribution_page was null. I added a title to the database, then the update runs. (started again from the original database)

Comment: Welcome to CiviStackExchange! I added backticks around your code blocks to make them readable - please remember to do that in the future.
The backtrace offers a clue but still not entirely clear. Can you verify that you followed the upgrade procedure and your database is at the correct version?

Comment: thanks will do code blocks in future.

Comment: I add some more informations. civicrm system status complains only about " MySQL Timezone Problem". Extenstions and core shoud be updated

Comment: I did incremental update now. Until 5.62.1 the site is working.

Comment: @coleman. I think I got it and all information I wrote are not relevant. Only participant searches are affected (most of my searches are for participants). Several operators are no longer available for participant role 5.63. So role_id:name IN Volunteer get changed to role_id:name CONTAINS "". I think this is a bug?

Comment: but the error "error_message "DB Error: no such field"" is still in browser console, but search results are shown at least.